# Force lld to link relocatables that use debug info in different DWARF versions

Tags: c++, android-ndk, linker, clang, llvm

There is a project that has a prebuilt dependencies (a bunch of static libs), all these libraries have debug info sections generated in default toolchain format - DWARF-4. I'm trying to compile my sources with `-gdwarf-5`, but linker fails to link final loadable binary:

> ld.lld: error: linking module flags 'Dwarf Version': IDs have conflicting values ('i32 4' from foo/bar/baz.cc with 'i32 5' from ld-temp.o)

Is there any way to convince linker to continue even if different TU use different DWARF versions? After some googling I've found this ticket https://reviews.llvm.org/D52952, where the same issue was reported as warning, which makes me think that there might be some chances to suppress it.

P.S. All above is about LLVM toolchain from Android NDK r20 (claims to be LLVM 8), linker is lld.

P.S.S. I have no chance to recompile dependencies, that is why I'm looking for a way to allow different DWARF versions in final binary.

Answer (score 0):

The NDK defaults to passing `-Wl,--fatal-warnings` to the linker because the most common type of linker warning is that something isn't defined, which means your app is broken. More warnings have been added to the linkers over the years, and some (and I believe this is the case here) are fairly innocuous.

Unfortunately, as far as I know there's no way to control the fatal warnings on a per-warning basis like you can with `-Werror=warning-name` with the compiler. If you're okay with disabling *all* of the fatal linker warnings, you can disable that feature with `-Wl,--no-fatal-warnings` (add it to your ldflags). If you're using ndk-build you can do this on a per-module basis with `LOCAL_DISABLE_FATAL_LINKER_WARNINGS := true`.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried `-Wl,--no-fatal-warnings` - same error. I forgot to add an important detail - both prebuilt stuff and source compilation are `-flto`, so it looks like this error comes from mismatch in bitcode metadata that comes to the final link stage. If it is possible to ask lld in LTO mode to ignore this meta and use user-supplied DWARF version to generate debug sections - it would solve my problem I guess.

Comment: Check your link command (the actual invocation of lld if possible, but the clang command will probably tell you what you need as well). Check to make sure that your `-Wl,--no-fatal-warnings` not only is used, but comes *after* `-Wl,--fatal-warnings`. If it comes first then it'll be overridden. It could also be that this is just always an error with LTO. Using LTO on libraries that weren't built with the same compiler and flags is something that's always going to cause trouble.